# PHP MVC Add to array on post

Tags: php, arrays, model-view-controller

I have the below code and whenever I post a value it doesn't add it to the array. It is like it creates a new array with only the value I posted.

```
<?php

class Model
{
    public $task;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->task = array();
    }
}

class Controller
{
    public $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function addTask($taskToAdd)
    {
        array_push( $this->model->task, $taskToAdd);
    }
}

class View
{
    public $model;
    public $controller;

    public function __construct(Controller $controller, Model $model)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function drawScreen()
    {
        $htmlForm = "<!doctype HTML>";
        $htmlForm = $htmlForm . "<html><head><title>php form test</title></head>";
        $htmlForm = $htmlForm . "<body>";
        $htmlForm = $htmlForm . "<form method='POST' action='index.php'>";
        $htmlForm = $htmlForm . "<input type='text' name='newtask' />";
        $htmlForm = $htmlForm . "<input type='submit' value='Add new task' />";
        $htmlForm = $htmlForm . "</form></body></html>";

        echo $htmlForm;
    }

    public function listTasks()
    {
        print_r($this->model->task);
    }
}

    $model = new Model();

    $controller = new Controller($model);

    $view = new View($controller, $model);

if (isset($_POST['newtask'])) {
    $taskToAdd = $_POST['newtask'];
    $controller->addTask($taskToAdd);
}

echo $view->drawScreen();
echo $view->listTasks();
```

Not really sure what I am doing wrong here. Is array_push not the correct way? I am using xampp if it makes any difference. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You have to save your model to a database and load it from there everytime. Because your PHP code compiles the script again and again and destroys your model everytime. Try to think like the computer, what would you do if you get these instructions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that each time you the user submit the form - is new execution of your php script.
So - your array - is not the same array from the last time.

To do what you want - you can use [Session](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) for example.

Comment: Ok I got it. Is like the states in .net

Comment: I'm not sure what your goal of your code is but you could also build up an array of arrays in JavaScript and then at some point send all those arrays to PHP to handle.